# how to convert the normal working website to ipad/iphone compatible?

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad

how to convert the normal working website to ipad/iphone compatible?
Any freeware tools available to convert normal website to ipad/iphone compatible?

Answer (score 3):

There are thousands of tutorials for this.

I suggest to start of with something like

> http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-web-app-meta-tags/

Then, if you're not happy you can re-design your side with a fluid layout

> http://cssgrid.net/

Or, you can do everything from scratch and use a Mobile framework, the ones that are most used this days are:

[JQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/) (now maintaned by Jonathan Stark), [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) (from jQuery Team) and [Sencha Touch](http://Sencha.com/Touch) (from ExtJs Developers that hired the jQTouch creator as well)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by "ipad/iphone compatible".

If you just want the website to work, that's most likely already the case if the website works on WebKit browsers (which it usually should if it works on other popular browsers like Firefox and Chrome, other than a few quirks).

If you just want to define the default viewport zoom to make the page more readable and easier to navigate, consider adding `<meta>` with configuration for the `viewport` options.

However, to truly utilize mobile/tablets devices and maximize the user experience, there's no real way to "magically" transform your regular desktop-based site to a mobile/tablet optimized one. For that, you need a new mobile-optimized website.

You need a completely different approach and mind-set when building mobile websites - the interface and functionality should be much more minimalistic, focusing on the truly important aspects of your sites. The layout should highlight the important areas of the site, and most of the "background noise" should be discarded. The navigation needs to be optimized to be used by a touch screen, and in general the entire touch-based user interaction allows you to do things very differently than classic websites.

There are plenty of good resources you can find online. SmashingMagazine has a great [introductory post](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/03/how-to-build-a-mobile-website/) to mobile design, which is by no means comprehensive, but it is a good starting point.

If you do decide to write a dedicated mobile version, I highly suggested trying [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) which I really enjoy working with.

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of sites to convert your website to mobile compatible.
Here is one which I would say good for Apple : http://www.appypie.com/

But ofcourse you can try paid software too.